# pyftpdlib make os.makedirs permission denied

Tags: python, linux

I am reading a ftp platform code based on pyftpdlib, and this code cannot run on my Linux.
I use sudo to ensure the permission.

When pyftpdlib run my code and then my code run os.makedirs and this throw a permission error.

I can run it in other python code without pyftpdlib.

This is the Traceback:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 83, in read
    obj.handle_read_event()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 444, in handle_read_event
    self.handle_read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/asynchat.py", line 158, in handle_read
    self.found_terminator()
  File "pyftpdlib/ftpserver.py", line 2230, in found_terminator
    self.process_command(cmd, arg)
  File "pyftpdlib/ftpserver.py", line 2296, in process_command
    method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pyftpdlib/ftpserver.py", line 3193, in ftp_PASS
    rst = self.authorizer.validate_authentication(self.username, line)
  File "ftp9/auth.py", line 42, in validate_authentication
    self._group_info.update(api)
  File "ftp9/group.py", line 64, in update
    self._update_fs()
  File "ftp9/group.py", line 143, in _update_fs
    walk(self._root, config.FTP_ROOT)
  File "ftp9/group.py", line 141, in walk
    walk(i, pjoin(rootdir, i.name))
  File "ftp9/group.py", line 125, in walk
    os.makedirs(pjoin(rootdir, i))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/ftp/\xe6\x9c\xac\xe7\xa7\x91\xe7\x94\x9f/1997\xe7\xba\xa7'
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code that you tried to run please?

Answer (score 0):

This code will run on the Linux user "ftp", so It does not have the permission of the folder. you should chown to give the permission.